# Please help me understand Django GenericInlineFormSet

Tags: django

Django ContentTypes provides a GenericInlineFormSet, however [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-in-forms-and-admin) does not explain how to use it, except for [this test](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/), which doesn't really explain it in a way I understand.

Please can you help me understand it?

Let's say I have the following classes

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    breed = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dog'


class Fish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    habitat = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Fish'


class Pet(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
                               ContentType,
                               limit_choices_to={'model__in':('dog', 'fish')},
                               verbose_name='Species'
                               )
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=64,  verbose_name='Animal')
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [("content_type", "object_id")]
```

What does the view look like to display a form for a Pet?

Comment: Never used it, but why don't you give it a try?

Comment: I spent two hours today trying to get it to work... I got very confused.

Answer (score 0):

GenericInlineFormSet works just like a standard [inline formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), except that it uses generic relations rather than standard foreign keys.

Comment: Sure, that explains why it's called what it is! So how would you create one for the above example?

Comment: This is demonstrably untrue.  The source code for each shows that the genericInlineFormset doesn't use the parameters the InlineFormset works. There are multiple cases, but for InlineFormset, you can set '`save_as_new`', which you can't set for the GenericInlineFormset, even though it shows it in its parameter list.  It literally does nothing with that variable.